# My hamburger drop-down menu appears behind my slider in the 'How it works' page on Mobile and Pagination is mixed-up with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

If you visit the swiper.js site under Demos, I have tried to replicate slider number 7 with the heading 'Custom Pagination' [Refer: Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/demos/).

Everything seems to work fine with my slider save for 2 things:

1. The pagination bullets that should appear at the bottom of the page
   are mixed up with the text and I would like that they appear like
   5px below the last sentence.
2. When in mobile view my hamburger drop-down menu appears behind the
   slider rather than in front of the slider.

I have pasted my code below for the above problem, the page you should click on is titled, 'How it works'. If I have left out any other instruction that might be of assistance kindly let me know and I will update my code. I have also downloaded the swiper.min.js and swiper.min.css in my root folder so kindly do not think I forgot that.

```css
body{
    background: #F0F8EA;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    background: #E54B4B;
    color: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
}
header::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.logo ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.logo a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo a:hover,
.logo a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}
.navbar-nav{
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}
.navbar-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 130%;
    right: .75em;
}
.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}

.site-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #464655;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
    /* display: none; */
}
.site-nav--open{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.site-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.site-nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}
.site-nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.site-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em 4.5em;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus{
    background: #E4B363;
    color: #464655;
}
.site-nav--icon{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 0.7em;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.menu-toggle{
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: .75em;
    right: .75em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #f8f4f4;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.95em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.hamburger::before{
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
.hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
.open .hamburger{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.open .hamburger::before{
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
@media (min-width: 1077px){
    .menu-toggle{
        display: none;
    }
    .site-nav{
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: transparent;
        float: right;
        clip-path: initial;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 1.2em;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        padding-top: 7px;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: transparent;
    }
    .site-nav li .fa{
        display: none;   
    }
}


.content-section{
    background: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #131212;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(15, 15, 15);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.form-group{
    margin-top: -24px;
  }
  .btn{
    background: rgb(41, 159, 180);
  }
  h5{
      color: #ffff;
  }
  h6{
     color: #ffff; 
  }
  .register{
    background: #dbd7d7;
  }


html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eee;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    color: #000;
    background: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SakaHapa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>PURCHASES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>POPULAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off site-nav--icon"></i>Log Out</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Slide man</h2>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the 
                            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
                            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Mafans</h2>
                        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
                            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is 
                            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
                            'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                            publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default 
                            model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
                            their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, 
                            sometimes on purpose.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
            <script>
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.swiper-pagination',
                        clickable: true,
                        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                        },
                    },
                });
            </script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x96dw0z8/1/ for the code since it uses external libraries, the snippet is not running properly.

Comment: the mobile hamburger is still displaying behind the slider

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to .site-nav

```
.site-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #464655;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
    /* display: none; */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #F0F8EA;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    background: #E54B4B;
    color: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
}
header::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.logo ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.logo a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo a:hover,
.logo a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}
.navbar-nav{
    outline: none;
    float: right;
}
.navbar-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 130%;
    right: .75em;
}
.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus{
    color: #464655;
}

.site-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background: #464655;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
    /* display: none; */
    z-index: 1;
}
.site-nav--open{
    clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.site-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.site-nav li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}
.site-nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.site-nav a{
    color: #f8f4f4;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em 4.5em;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus{
    background: #E4B363;
    color: #464655;
}
.site-nav--icon{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 0.7em;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
.menu-toggle{
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: .75em;
    right: .75em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #f8f4f4;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.95em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.hamburger::before{
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}
.hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
.open .hamburger{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.open .hamburger::before{
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}
@media (min-width: 1077px){
    .menu-toggle{
        display: none;
    }
    .site-nav{
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: transparent;
        float: right;
        clip-path: initial;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 1.2em;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        padding-top: 7px;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: transparent;
    }
    .site-nav li .fa{
        display: none;   
    }
}


.content-section{
    background: #f8f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #131212;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(15, 15, 15);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.form-group{
    margin-top: -24px;
  }
  .btn{
    background: rgb(41, 159, 180);
  }
  h5{
      color: #ffff;
  }
  h6{
     color: #ffff; 
  }
  .register{
    background: #dbd7d7;
  }


html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eee;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    color: #000;
    background: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SakaHapa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>PURCHASES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>POPULAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off site-nav--icon"></i>Log Out</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Slide man</h2>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the 
                            release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
                            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h2>Mafans</h2>
                        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable 
                            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is 
                            that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 
                            'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop 
                            publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default 
                            model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
                            their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, 
                            sometimes on purpose.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
            <script>
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.swiper-pagination',
                        clickable: true,
                        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                        },
                    },
                });
            </script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No change when i add it, still behaves the same

Comment: @M.Mayieko check my snippet.

Comment: I can see that it is working on your side, i do not know then what might be the problem it is not displaying on my side.

Comment: I get it, you have not used the swiper.min.css or swiper.min.js in your code. That is why you have managed to make the drop-down menu to appear in-front of the text. However, i cannot use the slider because the pagination functionality has been disabled. Kindly note in my code i have attached a link on my head as <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.min.css"> and on my body as <script type="text/javascript" src="swiper.min.js"></script> which enable the swiper-slider  functionality.